# linux - columns with width position

Tags: linux

I need columns to be with width position.is it possible ?

right now:

```
Z_mn_BS_1   2/01/2017 03:09:11  02/23/2017 01:02:51  FA     
Z_mn_BS_1   2/01/2017       03:09:11       02/23/2017 01:02:51  FA
```

But i need :

```
Z_mn_BS_1   2/01/2017 03:09:11  02/23/2017 01:02:51  FA     
Z_mn_BS_1   2/01/2017 03:09:11  02/23/2017 01:02:51  FA
```

Comment: please reformat your question. The input and expected output look the same to me

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `column -t file`

`man column` for more information.